# Why won't raspbian run on my pi?

Tags: raspbian, retropie

Okay. here's the scoop

I'm really new to raspberry pi (uncle had to assemble and code) and I already have two SD cards
-One with Retropie
-The other with Raspbian
The one with Retropie works fine, boots up as normal
The one with Raspbian on the other hand, doesn't go as smooth... when I insert this SD card, the pi doesn't even give a signal to my TV...

Any insight to this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: does the green led on raspberry pi flash a particular number of times? that can indicate what's wrong with the raspbian image on the SD card

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have not done anything with the Raspian card yet you could follow the instructions on building a new card it may be the fastest method.

Make sure that as someone new to PI that you go ahead and use the version with desktop.

Install guide and download is available here:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

I am making a quick assumption that the hardware is good because the other distribution works.